# Stop loss mechanics while backstesting on time series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, algorithmic-trading, back-testing

I'm presented with the following problem. I have time series data of prices and through the use of the "loc" method I was able to create a new column "trade" that stores the close price at a certain moment based on some condition to emulate an actual trade for later use in order to calculate return:

```
df.loc[(df.iloc[:, 2] + df.iloc[:, 3] + df.iloc[:, 4] == len(
    ind_list) - lim) & (df.iloc[:, 5] == 1), 'Trade'] = df.Close

df.loc[(df.iloc[:, 2] + df.iloc[:, 3] + df.iloc[:, 4] == -len(
    ind_list) + lim) & (d f.iloc[:, 5] == -1), 'Trade'] = -df.Close
 df = df.fillna(0)
```

Basically, this will give something like this:

```
Close  Volume ...   Trade
1003     40   ...     0
990      30   ...   -990
995      20   ...   -995
950      20   ...     0
960      20   ...   -960
950      34   ...     0
1000     20   ...   -1000
1050     20   ...   1050
1020     40   ...   1020
1010     30   ...     0
1005     20   ...   -1005
1000     20   ...   -1000
990      20   ...     0
970      20   ...    970
```

The dataframe in question has many rows but continues filling the trade column with the prices at the moment it puts a buy signal (in negative) or a sell signal (positive). Later on I filter this dataframe like this:

```
df = df[df['Trade'] != 0]
df.loc[df.Trade.shift(1).apply(np.sign) == df.Trade.apply(np.sign), 'Trade'] = 0
df = df[df['Trade'] != 0]
```

This will filter all the unnecessary rows so that I can proceed to calculate returns:

```
Close Volume ...   Trade
990     30   ...   -990
1050     20   ...   1050
1005     20   ...  -1005
970      20   ...   970
```

I want to emulate a stop loss which means that I have to set a condition based on every first negative value that signals a "buy" after a positive one and then copy a positive value from the close column to the trade column signaling a "sell" if the condition is meet. If the condition is to sell when the price is less than 40 than the buying price I clean the data set and use "ffill" on a new column. This will look like this:

```
 Close  Volume ...   Trade  Stop Loss Condition
990      30   ...   -990         950 (990-40 = 950)
995      20   ...   -995         950
950      20   ...    950         950    ---> True Stop Loss
960      20   ...   -960         950 (Should be 920 now)
950      34   ...    950         950    ---> False Stop Loss (Hasn't updated)
1000     20   ...   -1000        950  ---> False buy
1050     20   ...   1050         950
1020     40   ...   1020         950
1005     20   ...   -1005        965 (Condition updated since this was the original)
1000     20   ...   -1000        965 
970      20   ...    970         965
```

As you can see one of the issues that I'm having happens when the stop loss condition is triggered 2 or more times before the next buy signal creating an error since this condition should have been updated based on the new buying price that appeared right after the stop loss and before the original selling price of 1050.
Now the trades after filtering are these:

```
Close Volume ...   Trade
990     30   ...   -990
950      20   ...   950 --- > Good
960      20   ...  -960 -- > Good- Should've been update condition
950      34   ...   950 ---> Bad - This Shouldn't have happened
1000     20   ...  -1000 ---> Bad
1050     20   ...   1050
1005     20   ...  -1005
970      20   ...   970
```

In order to fix this issue I created some sort of loop to basically update the condition column after I "emulated" a stop loss. After this, I execute again in case the stop loss is triggered for a third time or fourth time before the next original selling price. The problem is that this created a bottleneck in my script and reduced the performance dramatically.

This is my solution:

```
    for h in range(3):
       trade = df['Trade']
       trade = trade[trade != 0]
       trade.loc[trade.shift(1).apply(np.sign) == trade.apply(np.sign)] = 0
       trade = trade[trade != 0]
       df = df.merge(trade.rename('T1'), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
       df['T1'] = df['T1'].fillna(method='ffill')
       df.loc[(df.T1 < 0) & (df.Close < df.T1.abs() * stop), 'Trade'] = df['Close']  # Applies the stop loss condition on long
       df.loc[(df.T1 > 0) & (df.Close > df.T1.abs() / stop), 'Trade'] = df['Close']  # Applies the stop loss condition on short
       df.drop(columns=['T1'], inplace=True)

    df = df[df['Trade'] != 0]
    df.loc[df.Trade.shift(1).apply(np.sign) == df.Trade.apply(np.sign), 'Trade'] = 0
    df = df[df['Trade'] != 0]
```

Is there a more efficient and simple way to do this using pandas/numpy? Also, it would be good to avoid creating this "T1" auxiliary column.

Thanks for reading this whole explanation

Comment: You may like to convert buy/sell signals into explicit position column first, and then manage your position with stop-loss signals. That will make it much easier.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I believe this is what I did, however, could you show me an example?

Comment: I don’t see position column in your code. Trade column is the delta of your capital.